# how to go to a new view based on a certain condition in StoryBoards in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, storyboard

I am new to iPhone Application Development , I am using XCode 4.2 with a storyboard

I have a tab based application and I want to find a way to do a certain algoritm

if (x==0)
{
go to view 1
}

else if (x==1)
{
go to view 2
}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this method of [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create segues in Xcode from your initial view to views 1 and 2 (ctrl drag) and give each an identifier.

Then use the method `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` to go each view depending on your condition.